# Tarski axioms of real numbers

Tags: logic, real-numbers, axioms

How does the Tarski axioms of real numbers imply that for each x,y,z ( x<y if and only if x+z < y+z ) ?

By using the 1st and 6th axioms it's easy to demonstrate that x+z<y+z implies x<y. But how can I show the equivalence?

Comment: Could you state what the axioms are?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals

Comment: "The three axioms imply that R is a linear continuum. "   Okay, so we need to wrap our heads that somehow if $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and $x \ne y$ then $x < y$ or $y-x$.  I haven't quite worked my brain around that but then if $x< y$ we have to figure either $x+z =y+z$ or $x+z > y+z$ or $x + z < y+z$.  Then first two one implies $x =y$ which we know is false the second impliex $x > y$ or $z < z$ and we know those are false so that only leaves $x< y$

Comment: Oh wait  "Tarski stated, without proof, that these axioms gave a total ordering. The missing component was supplied in 2008 by Stefanie Ucsnay."  So I'm not sure what "linear continuum" means if it doesn't imply total order.  And if it took ***72*** years for someone to provide that crucial step then.... I'm not sure what we can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...it was a given exercise on a text, so I'm quite sure it can be done! I'm just wondering how!

Comment: Play with it.  If we can prove that $x+z=y+z\implies x=y$ and we can prove that if $a \ne b$ then either $a < b$ or $b < a$ then we are done.  $x+z<y+z\implies x<z$ as you noted.  Then if $\lnot(x+z < y+z)\implies x+z = y+z\lor y+z<x+z\implies x=y\lor y< x\implies \lnot(x< y)$.  So by contrapositive the statements are equivalent.  ... I'm unfamilar with Tarski and I don't have paper or pencil in front of me so I'm having a hard time proving my two assumptions but presumably they can be proven.